# Conda Index Error: Invalid Index File

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I currently use Python 3.6.3. I reinstalled my Anaconda navigator. Now when I try to update conda or install anything with the Anaconda Prompt, I run into this error:

```
(C:\Users\armch\Anaconda3) C:\Users\armch>conda update conda
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaIndexError: Invalid index file: https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-
64/repodata.json.bz2: Failed to parse: proxy.yourorg.org:port
```

Also, I run into errors when I import any packages on Jupyter after reinstalling Anaconda.

Does anyone have the same experience before?

Below is my conda config --show

```
C:\Users\armch>conda config --show
add_anaconda_token: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
allow_non_channel_urls: True
allow_softlinks: False
always_copy: False
always_softlink: False
always_yes: False
anaconda_upload: None
auto_update_conda: True
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: True
channels:
  - defaults
client_ssl_cert: None
client_ssl_cert_key: None
clobber: False
create_default_packages: []
custom_channels:
  pkgs/main: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/free: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/r: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/msys2: https://repo.continuum.io/
custom_multichannels:
  defaults: ["https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2"]
  local: []
default_channels:
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2
disallow: []
envs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\armch\Anaconda3\envs
  - C:\Users\armch\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
  - C:\Users\armch\.conda\envs
force: False
json: False
local_repodata_ttl: 1
migrated_channel_aliases: []
non_admin_enabled: True
offline: False
path_conflict: clobber
pinned_packages: []
pkgs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\armch\Anaconda3\pkgs
  - C:\Users\armch\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
proxy_servers:
  http: http://172.30.144.234:8080
  https: http://172.30.144.234:8080
quiet: False
remote_connect_timeout_secs: 9.15
remote_max_retries: 3
remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0
rollback_enabled: True
shortcuts: True
show_channel_urls: True
ssl_verify: False
track_features: []
use_pip: True
verbosity: 0
```

Comment: Can you try `conda clean -i`?

Comment: @darthbith I did it and still got the same CondaIndexError when I try to update conda.

Comment: Can you please edit the output of `conda config --show` into your post?

Comment: @darthbith I just did. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure those proxy server settings are correct? It looks like from the original error message that there is a problem with the proxy servers

Comment: @darthbith I'm completely new to this so I'm not sure either. How can I make sure my proxy is set up correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea. If you're at work, check with your IT department. If you're at home, check where they're set within the system, and check with your ISP if they're necessary.